# Why does new fail?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In scala this is ok

```
val v = Vector(1,2,3)
```

This is not ok

```
val v = new Vector(1,2,3);
```

You get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                  //|   at scala.collection.immutable.VectorIterator.next(Vector.scala:660)
                                                  //|   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
                                                  //|   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
                                                  //|   at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
                                                  //|   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
                                                  //|   at scala.
```

Why?

Comment: Vector should be called without the new.  Calling it with new as indicated by the Scaladocs is a bug, https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7373

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the api http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector

You are trying to invoke the constructor that looks like this:

> new Vector(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int, focus: Int)

with this:

> val v = new Vector(1,2,3);

Looks like it is trying to reach the index at 3, but clearly the vector is not long enough